# Задача на реализацию двусвязного списка на c#

Tags: c#, двусвязный-список

К сути вопроса: реализовал двусвязный список, не спрашивайте зачем, знаю что есть такой уже в генериках. И все вроде как работает) НО, отправляю на тест, гдето в системе тестирования появляется ошибка NullReferenceException? Где что точно не указано. Блоками трай кэч все обложил - ничего не помогло. Гляньте кому интересно что не так?
Класс элемента списка, хотя это и не важно:

```
     //элемент связанного списка
public class ListItem : IListItem
{
    public ListItem prev { get; set; }
    public ListItem next { get; set; }
    private object _val;
    public ListItem(object obj, IListItem prev = null)
    {
        if (obj!=null)
        {
            this._val = obj;
        }

    }

    //предыдущий связанный элемент списка
    public IListItem Prev()
    {
        try
        {
            return prev;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            return new ListItem(999);
        }
    }
    public void invalidate()
    {
        prev = null;
        next = null;
        _val = null;
    }

    //следующий связанный элемент списка
    public IListItem Next()
    {
        try
        {
            return next;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            return new ListItem(999);
        }

    }

    //хранимое значение
    public object Value { get {
            if (_val != null)
            {
                return this._val;
            }
            else return null;

        } }
}

    Сам класс:


     //прямой связанный список
public class LinkedList : ILinkedList
{
    private ListItem head;

    public int count;
    public LinkedList()
    {
        count = 0;
    }

    //добавить элемент в начало
    public void AddFirst(IListItem item)
    {                    
        if (item == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (head==null)
        {
            AddToEmtyist(item);
            return;
        }
        ListItem newItem = (ListItem)item;
        newItem.next = head;
        newItem.prev = head.prev;
        head.prev.next = newItem;
        head.prev = newItem;
        head = newItem;
        count++;           
    }

    //добавить элемент в конец
    public void AddLast(IListItem item)
    {   
        if (item == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (head == null)
        {
            AddToEmtyist(item);
            return;
        }

        ListItem newItem = (ListItem)item;
        newItem.next = head;
        newItem.prev = head.prev;
        head.prev.next = newItem;
        head.prev = newItem;            
        count++;            
    }

    private void AddToEmtyist(IListItem item)
    {
        try
        {           
        ListItem newItem = (ListItem)item;
        newItem.next = newItem;
        newItem.prev = newItem;
        head = newItem;
        count++;
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }



    //вставить элемент перед элементом с указанным индексом
    //если элемента нет - вставить в конец
    public void Insert(IListItem item, int index)
    {
        try
        {


        if (item==null)
        {
            return;
        }
        int i = 0;
        ListItem replaceItem = head;
        if (index > (count-1))
        {
            AddLast(item);
            return;
        }
        if (index==0)
        {
            AddFirst(item);
        }
        while (index != i)
        {
            replaceItem = replaceItem.next;
            i++;
        }

        ListItem newItem = (ListItem)item;

        newItem.next = replaceItem;
        newItem.prev = replaceItem.prev;

        replaceItem.prev.next = newItem;
        replaceItem.prev = newItem;

        count++;
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {


        }
    }

    //проверка есть ли эелементы в списке
    public bool IsEmpty()
    {
        if (count > 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else return true;
    }

    //вернуть первый эелемент в списке
    public IListItem GetFirstItem()
    {
        if (head != null)
        {
            return head;
        }
        else return null;

    }

    //вернуть все элементы списка, кроме первого
    public IEnumerable<IListItem> GetAll()
    {
        if (count==0)
        {
            return null;
        }
        List<IListItem> rez = new List<IListItem>();
        int cnt = 0;
        ListItem currItem = head;
        while (cnt != (count))
        {
            if (currItem!=head)
            {
               rez.Add(currItem);
            } 
            currItem = currItem.next;
            cnt++;
        }
        return rez;
    }

    //очистить список
    public void Clear()
    {
        ListItem current =(ListItem)head;
        while (current != null)
        {
            ListItem temp = current;
            current = (ListItem)current.Next();
            temp.invalidate();
        }

        head = null;
        count = 0;
    }

    //сортировка списка в обратном порядке
    public void Reverse()
    {
        ListItem node = head;
        do
        {
            ListItem temp = node.next;
            node.next = node.prev;
            node.prev = temp;
            node = node.prev;
            if (temp == head)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        while (true);

        head = head.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Полный пример если что - https://github.com/magregar/LinkedistTask.git

Answer (score 2):

Воспроизвести проблему просто

```
    var l = new LinkedList();   

    foreach (var i in l.GetAll()) // l.GetAll() вернет null
    {
    }
```

Накидал комментариев по коду

```
// Что не так:
public class ListItem : IListItem
{
    public ListItem prev { get; set; }
    public ListItem next { get; set; }
    private object _val;
```

prev не используется

```
    public ListItem(object obj, IListItem prev = null)
    {
        if (obj != null)
        {
            this._val = obj;
        }

    }

    //предыдущий связанный элемент списка
    public IListItem Prev()
    {
        try
        {
```

тут, при данном коде, никгда не будет исключения

```
            return prev;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            return new ListItem(999);
        }
    }
    public void invalidate()
    {
        prev = null;
        next = null;
        _val = null;
    }

    //следующий связанный элемент списка
    public IListItem Next()
    {
        try
        {
```

Быть тут не может исключения, это просто возврат ссылки

```
            return next;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            return new ListItem(999);
        }

    }

    //хранимое значение
    public object Value
    {
        get
        {
```

вся конструкция заменяется на return this._val

```
            if (_val != null)
            {
                return this._val;
            }
            else return null;

        }
    }
}




     //прямой связанный список
public class LinkedList : ILinkedList
{
    private ListItem head;

    public int count;
    public LinkedList()
    {
        count = 0;
    }

    //добавить элемент в начало
    public void AddFirst(IListItem item)
    {
        if (item == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (head == null)
        {
            AddToEmtyist(item);
            return;
        }
        ListItem newItem = (ListItem)item;
        newItem.next = head;
```

head.prev по логике всегда null

```
        newItem.prev = head.prev;
```

если head.prev == null, то будет исключение

```
        head.prev.next = newItem;
        head.prev = newItem;
        head = newItem;
        count++;
    }

    //добавить элемент в конец
    public void AddLast(IListItem item)
    {
        if (item == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (head == null)
        {
            AddToEmtyist(item);
            return;
        }

        ListItem newItem = (ListItem)item;
        newItem.next = head;
```

head.prev по логике всегда null

```
        newItem.prev = head.prev;
```

если head.prev == null, то будет исключение

```
        head.prev.next = newItem;
        head.prev = newItem;
        count++;
    }

    private void AddToEmtyist(IListItem item)
    {
        try
        {
            ListItem newItem = (ListItem)item;
```

для чего следующий и предыдущий указывают на одно и то же, причем на себя?

```
            newItem.next = newItem;
            newItem.prev = newItem;
            head = newItem;
            count++;
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
```

Если будет исклчение, оно тут не остановится - сами запускаете его дальше

```
            throw;
        }
    }



    //вставить элемент перед элементом с указанным индексом
    //если элемента нет - вставить в конец
    public void Insert(IListItem item, int index)
    {
        try
        {


            if (item == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            int i = 0;
            ListItem replaceItem = head;
            if (index > (count - 1))
            {
                AddLast(item);
                return;
            }
            if (index == 0)
            {
                AddFirst(item);
            }
            while (index != i)
            {
                replaceItem = replaceItem.next;
                i++;
            }

            ListItem newItem = (ListItem)item;

            newItem.next = replaceItem;
            newItem.prev = replaceItem.prev;

            replaceItem.prev.next = newItem;
            replaceItem.prev = newItem;

            count++;
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {


        }
    }

    //проверка есть ли эелементы в списке
    public bool IsEmpty()
    {
        if (count > 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else return true;
    }

    //вернуть первый эелемент в списке
    public IListItem GetFirstItem()
    {
        // просто return head;
        if (head != null)
        {
            return head;
        }
        else return null;

    }

    //вернуть все элементы списка, кроме первого
    public IEnumerable<IListItem> GetAll()
    {
        if (count == 0)
        {
```

Возвращаешь null как результат - получаешь nullreferenceexceprion в вызывающем коде. 
Возвращай `Enumerable.Empty<IListItem>();`

```
            return null;
        }
        List<IListItem> rez = new List<IListItem>();
        int cnt = 0;
        ListItem currItem = head;
```

Зачем тут вообще счетчики? Просто перебирай список пока не кончится.

```
        while (cnt != (count))
        {
            if (currItem != head)
            {
                rez.Add(currItem);
            }
            currItem = currItem.next;
            cnt++;
        }
        return rez;
    }

    //очистить список
    public void Clear()
    {
        ListItem current = (ListItem)head;
        while (current != null)
        {
            ListItem temp = current;
            current = (ListItem)current.Next();
            temp.invalidate();
        }

        head = null;
        count = 0;
    }

    //сортировка списка в обратном порядке
    public void Reverse()
    {
        ListItem node = head;
        do
        {
            ListItem temp = node.next;
            node.next = node.prev;
            node.prev = temp;
            node = node.prev;
            if (temp == head)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        while (true);

        head = head.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Так это ведь двусвязный список, у head ссылки на себя в prev и next. Microsoft сделал так у себя в реализации linkedlist.

Comment: @АндрейАнфилец Вы смотрите на их внутреннюю реализацию и меняете свой контракт. У MS [указатель на Next  будет возвращать null даже есть в поле внутри стоит head](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/linkedlist.cs,624) А у вас не так.